# How can I spread a list of strings repectively?

Tags: python, list, graph, tree

Given an input list as:

```
l=[["A","B"],["C","D","E"],["F","G"]]
```

What I wanted to make with this list is:

```
o = ["ACF", "ACG", "ADF", "ADG", "AEF", "AEG",
     "BCF", "BCG", "BDF", "BDG", "BEF", "BEG"]
```

At first, I tried to generate a list of `len`, and multiple with standard function `reduce` and functools's `mul`.

```
ls = list(map(len,l))
ll = ["" for i in range(reduce(mul, ls, 1))]
```

Next, I don't have efficient or "pythonic" idea to solve this.

By the way, this seems to be similar problem with tree traversal, but I thought this is multiple-parent tree or problem related to graph implementation.

For efficiency in memory issue to deal with a huge list of lists, how can I solve this with python generator by using directed graph or any other algorithm?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> l=[["A","B"],["C","D","E"],["F","G"]]
>>> list(map(''.join,itertools.product(*l)))
['ACF', 'ACG', 'ADF', 'ADG', 'AEF', 'AEG', 'BCF', 'BCG', 'BDF', 'BDG', 'BEF', 'BEG']
```

From the documentation:

> Cartesian product of input iterables.
>   Roughly equivalent to nested for-loops in a generator expression. For example, product(A, B) returns the same as ((x,y) for x in A for y in B).